# Track if there is a mousedown/up in a subview from a NSPopover

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspopover

Here is my current object hierarchy:
A view has a button that opens an `NSPopover`, which contains another view (An `NSControl`)

I am listening for a mouseup event on my `NSPopover`, at which point I close my `NSPopover`.

However, I don't want it to close if I'm in the `NSControl` (i.e, if there was a mousedown/mouseup event in the `NSControl`)

So my plan is to identify when a mouseup/down event is found on the control, then ignore the `NSPopover` closing on my mouseup event listener in the `NSPopover`

Has anybody done anything like this before?  Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My solution ended up being tracking if the popover is open in the root view controller, and if the root view got a mouseup event, and the popover was open, I could break out of the code